# How to setup passport.js with graphql-yoga (prisma)

Tags: node.js, oauth, graphql, passport.js, prisma

how to setup passport.js with google-auth using graphql-yoga(prisma).
If somone want to help me please describe all setps you took to setup , thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this post might be a good start.

https://medium.com/@mjw56/graphql-authentication-with-passport-d75c08d5fbdc